# CodeName One IOS CaptureAudio

Tags: codenameone

I called captureAudio method from Capture class.

It opens an empty dialog box on IOS 7, with save/cancel buttons.
No audio bar shown to user understands recording.

It's ok on android.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS doesn't have a capture UI like Androids this is implemented entirely in Java. You can write your own implementation of this rather easily e.g. this is from the Codename One `IOSImplementation.java` file that does exactly that:

```
public void captureAudio(ActionListener response) {
    String p = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
    if(!p.endsWith("/")) {
        p += "/";
    }
    try {
        final Media media = MediaManager.createMediaRecorder(p + "cn1TempAudioFile", MediaManager.getAvailableRecordingMimeTypes()[0]);
        media.play();

        boolean b = Dialog.show("Recording", "", "Save", "Cancel");
        final Dialog d = new Dialog("Recording");

        media.pause();
        media.cleanup();
        d.dispose();
        if(b) {
            response.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(p + "cn1TempAudioFile"));
        } else {
            FileSystemStorage.getInstance().delete(p + "cn1TempAudioFile");
            response.actionPerformed(null);
        }
    } catch(IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        response.actionPerformed(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you shai,
can you add some events like DataReceive to detect data and interact with UI?

Comment: I think, there is many limitations on mobile frameworks to detect events of objects.

Comment: There are plenty of events, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Media class doesn't have any event. Capture class doesn't have any  event. I created an online web studio before, to record audio and video & mix them on timeline, and i had full control on these objects, during recording & playback.

Comment: Yes, the media class is designed to answer very simple use cases such as media player and business oriented app requirements. Its more challenging to create a common "low level" media API and we had no requirement to do so from enterprise/corporate or even pro grade users.